# Datagrid Binding/Grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `Persons` object of type `ObservableCollection<Person>` in my ViewModel "MainWindowModel". In the MainWindow I want to have a DataGrid with Grouping on "Sex". However, in the group headerline there appears always "M" for the sex:
 [image].

Is there an error in the data binding?

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:SimpleDatagridGrouping"

<Window.Resources>
    <viewmodel:MainWindowModel x:Key="vm" />

    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvsPersons" 
        Source="{Binding  Source={StaticResource vm}, Path=Persons}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Sex"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="GroupingHeader">
        <StackPanel Background="YellowGreen" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="Sex" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            <TextBlock  Margin="0,5,5,5"
                        Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource  cvsPersons}, 
                        Path=Sex}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Count" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid  DataContext="vm">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=cvsPersons}}"
              SelectionMode="Single" 
              Margin="10,0,10,10" 
              AlternationCount="2"                  
              VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              MinHeight="35">
        <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=GroupingHeader}"/>
        </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Forename" Binding="{Binding Forename}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Age" Binding="{Binding Age}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Sex" Binding="{Binding Sex}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**The View Model:**

```
public class Person
{
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Int32 Age { get; set; }
    public E_Sex Sex { get; set; }
    public Person(string forename_, string name_, Int32 age_, E_Sex sex_ )
        {...}
}//eoClass: Person

public class MainWindowModel : Notifier
{
    public MainWindowModel()
    {
        IList<Person> persons_ = new List<Person> ();
        persons_.Add ( new Person ( "Hans", "Müller", 23, E_Sex.M ) );
        //...
        this.persons = new ObservableCollection<Person> ( persons_ );
    }//eoCtor

    private ObservableCollection<Person> persons = null;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get { return this.persons; }
        set
        {
            this.persons = value;
            OnPropertyChanged ( "Persons" );
        }
    }
}//eoClass: MainWindowModel
```

Answer (score 0):

When you group, you don't get a person for the header to template.
What you get is one property called Name.
In your groupstyle you are expecting to get a person and bind it's properties:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupingHeader">
            .....
            <TextBlock 
                Margin="0,5,5,5"
                Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource  cvsPersons}, Path=Sex}" 
                />
```

Your template should be more like:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupingHeader">
            .....
            <TextBlock 
                Margin="0,5,5,5"
                Text="{Binding Name}"
```

You can see a full example here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-group-sort-and-filter-data-in-the-datagrid-control

If you look carefully at the picture of the output you will see "Project ...." in the headers. These are ProjectName. But the code binds Name.
That's because whatever you define as the sort descriptor is returned as a sort of special field called Name.

Comment: Thank you, you both (Nik & Andy) opened my eyes. Until now I thought that I get a person-object. It works as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected result, use this for your group header `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupingHeader">
    <StackPanel Background="YellowGreen" Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <TextBlock Text="Sex" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            <!--Bind to Name!!-->
            <TextBlock  Margin="0,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="Count" Margin="5,5,5,5"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="0,5,5,5" Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

So what's happening here? When you're Binding in this particular DataTemplate, you have to consider what the `DataContext` of the group header is, as that is what any Binding Looks for. So when you say: `Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsPersons}, Path=Sex}"`, you are saying go find StaticResource `cvsPersons` and Bind to its DataContext's property named `Sex`. I must admit, the behaviour you're getting is a bit strange, as that binding should just fail in my opinion (please correct me if I am wrong), but it looks like it finds the first person in the list and uses that Person's sex as the Value for all your headers. Try it, change the first person in your list to a Female, and all your headers will now say `F` instead of `M`.

So what is the `DataContext` of a Group Header? Well it is what is knows as a `CollectionViewGroup`, which has the following public properties: `Name`, `Items`, `ItemCount`. If you look closely, you are already Binding to `ItemCount` in your last `TextBlock` of the DataTemplate. The `Name`, is the value of the whatever it is you're grouping on, in your case being 'F', 'M'..., which will logically be unique for each group, and each item in any given group has the same value for the property the collection was grouped on.

Comment: Thank you, you both (Nik & Andy) opened my eyes. Until now I thought that I get a person-object. It works as suggested. And You're right, if I change the sex of first Person to female, I get "F" for all groups.

Comment: You're welcome @Ruebezaehler! Please consider selecting one of the answers that helped you the most as the accepted answer. This will help future readers get the best information. [See Here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358870/7159784) on how to select an answer as the accepted answer.